# Most likely position for random walk with symmetric jumps after $t$ steps

Tags: probability, random-variables, markov-chains, martingales, random-walk

Consider a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ starting at 0 with jump distribution $p(x)$ such that,

1. $p(x) = p(-x)$
2. $p(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Let $p^{\,t}(n)$ be the probability that the random walk is at $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ at time $t \in \mathbb{N}$. How to prove that, for any $t$ even and large enough,
$$
\max\{ p^t(n) \, ; \, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}
$$
is attained at $n=0$?

**Comment 1:** I probably need a proper *local* central limit theorem.

**Comment 2:** I am also trying to prove it by employing characteristic functions.

Comment: Your random walk starts at $0$ ?

Comment: Yes. See the edit.

Comment: A 1-D random walk is, in expectation, $O(\sqrt t)$ steps away from the origin after $t$ steps. The maximizing of $p_n^t$ at $n=0$ seems odd.

Comment: No, as the expected jump is 0, the random walk is expected to be at the origin at any $t$.

Comment: You probably mean jump from $n$ to $n\pm x$ ?

Comment: The position after $t$ jumps is the sum of the amplitudes of the individual jumps. Then you can apply the central limit theorem.

Comment: The central limit theorem implies that for any $\delta>0$, the probability to find the random walk at time $t$ in $[-\delta \cdot \sqrt{t}, + \delta \cdot \sqrt{t}]$ is uniformly positive in $t$, but it does not provide information on the maximum of the distribution. Indeed, if the random walk has  jump distribution $p^1_3= 1/2$, $p^1_{-3}=1/2$, then the return to the origin would be possible only at times multiples of $6$, and this would imply that $p^t_0$ is $0$ if $t$ is not a multiple of $6$.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that $p(n)$ is the probability of jumping from your current position $n$ steps ahead? If so, then $p(3)=\frac{1}{2}$ implies jumping back and forth three step is possible in $2$ turns?

Comment: Follow-up of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1487446/) (which could have been mentioned).

Comment: @QuantumLogarithm your example shows that $x$, not $t$ must be a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Discrete Fourier transform does the job neatly. For every integer-valued random variable $Y$, $$2\pi P(Y=n)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi E(e^{ixY})e^{-nix}dx,$$ Let $X$ be distributed like the increments of the random walk, then $$2\pi p^{2t}(n)=\int_{-\pi}^\pi E(e^{ixX})^{2t}e^{-nix}dx=\int_{-\pi}^\pi E(\cos(xX))^{2t}\cos(nx)dx,$$ because $X=-X$ in distribution hence $E(e^{ixX})=E(\cos(xX))$ is real valued. Since $E(\cos(xX))^{2t}\geqslant0$ and $|\cos(nx)|\leqslant1$, $$2\pi p^{2t}(n)\leqslant\int_{-\pi}^\pi E(\cos(xX))^{2t}dx=2\pi p^{2t}(0),$$ which proves the claim. (Note: Hypothesis 2. is off-topic.)