What is the 2nd most likely value of a Random Walk after time=t?
Here is a math problem I was thought of the other day involving Random Walks:
Let $X_t$, $t \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., n\}$, be a (discrete time) stochastic process where $$X_t \in \{-1, +1\}$$ $$P(X_t = +1) = P(X_t = -1) = 0.5$$.
Let  $Z_t$ as the position of $X_t$ at each turn $t$:
$$Z_t = \sum_{i=0}^{t} X_i$$
Using the standard properties of a Random Walk, we know that the position of this process at any given time is Normally Distributed. Using this property, we should be able to find out the mean position and variance after any time $t$.
Here is my question: Suppose at $t=0$, the process starts at position $0$.Let's say that we let this process run for $t=15$ steps. In this situation:

What is the most likely position this process will be after 15 steps?
What is the second most likely position this process will be after 15 steps?
What is the third most likely position this process will be after 15 steps?
etc.

On some level, the answer is somewhat obvious. The distribution of possible positions at time $t$ will begin to resemble a Gaussian Distribution (i.e. Bell Curve) as $t$ increases in size. Therefore, the mean value should be the most frequent - and positions closer to the mean value should relatively more frequent compared to positions farther away from the mean value. However, I would like to try and answer this question more mathematically to determine the exact probability that the process occupies any given position after a certain amount of time.
To answer this question, I thought that we can start by enumerating the sample space. After $t$ steps, how many unique values could the process have? I thought about this and naively thought that it can have (-$t$, $t$) number of positions. E.g. if $t$ = 15, then  : -15 if 15 consecutive -1 , +15 if 15 consecutive +1 ... and everything else in between. But I am not sure if this logic is correct (e.g. need to account for odd valued $t$ vs even valued $t$).
However, I am not sure if there is some mathematical function (e.g. combinatorial, probability generator function) which can be used to determine the number of ways a certain position can be reached. If this was possible, then I would be able to find all possible ways to end up with all possible positions, and then rank each one in terms of frequency.
Can someone please suggest how to work on this problem?
Note: Currently, I am using a computer simulation (in R) to experiment with this problem and enumerate all possible paths and frequencies. For example, here are all the probabilities of all possible paths after 15 turns (I have posted the code in case anyone wants to play with this):
library(dplyr)

generate_all_paths <- function(num_turns) {
    if (num_turns == 0) {
        return(list(c()))
    } else {
        paths_plus <- generate_all_paths(num_turns - 1)
        paths_minus <- generate_all_paths(num_turns - 1)
        
        paths_plus <- lapply(paths_plus, c, 1)
        paths_minus <- lapply(paths_minus, c, -1)
        
        return(c(paths_plus, paths_minus))
    }
}

paths <- generate_all_paths(15)

df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(paths, function(x) { c(x, rep(NA, max(lengths(paths)) - length(x))) }))
df <- as.data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$final_score <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)

df <- df %>%
    group_by(final_score) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    mutate(probability = count / sum(count))

df

Now we can see the frequencies and probabilities of all possible paths for a particular process:
   final_score count probability
 1         -15     1   0.0000305
 2         -13    15   0.000458 
 3         -11   105   0.00320  
 4          -9   455   0.0139   
 5          -7  1365   0.0417   
 6          -5  3003   0.0916   
 7          -3  5005   0.153    
 8          -1  6435   0.196    
 9           1  6435   0.196    
10           3  5005   0.153    
11           5  3003   0.0916   
12           7  1365   0.0417   
13           9   455   0.0139   
14          11   105   0.00320  
15          13    15   0.000458 
16          15     1   0.0000305


Related Questions:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487673/most-likely-position-for-random-walk-with-symmetric-jumps-after-t-steps

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811859/most-likely-value-of-negative-binomial-random-variable

The simplest case is for $15$ and $-15$, exactly $2^{-15}$.

This link may be relevant to your interests: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Final value depends only on the number of $+1$s in the sequence. There are exactly $2^t$ possible sequences, each one of the same probability $2^{-t}$. You may choose $n$ $+1$s from $t$ on $t \choose n$ ways. So no need for a program, just a simple calculation.

thank you! does this change if the probabilities are non-symmetric and the step sizes are also non-symmetric? e.g. (0.3 probability of +1 and 0.7 probability of -1.1)?

Yes, it does significantly.

thank you for your reply ... by significantly, I meant : does the mathematical approach needed to solve this problem change significantly?

I posted a follow up question here in case you are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4939594/distribution-of-non-symmetric-random-walk
