Where will a Non-Symmetric Random Walk be after time=t?
I posted this question about ranking the final position of a symmetric random walk after $t$ steps in terms of likelihood: What is the 2nd most likely value of a Random Walk after time=t?
I am now wondering - what happens if the process is non-symmetric?
For example:
Let $X_t$, $t \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., n\}$, be a (discrete time) stochastic process where:
$$X_t \in \{m, n\} $$
$$m\neq n$$ $$P(X_t = m) = p1$$
$$ m, n \in \mathbb{Z} $$
$$ P(X_t = n) = 1-p1 $$
$$P(X_t = m) = 1-p1 = p2$$
$$ p1 \neq p2 $$
Let  $Z_t$ as the position of $X_t$ at each turn $t$:
$$Z_t = \sum_{i=0}^{t} X_i$$
Here is my question: Suppose at $t=0$, the process starts at position $0$.Let's say that we let this process run for $t=15$ steps. In this situation:

What is the most likely position this process will be after 15 steps?
What is the second most likely position this process will be after 15 steps?
What is the third most likely position this process will be after 15 steps?
etc.

I am not sure if the same mathematical approach (relying on symmetry) from the previous question can be applied to this question.
Can someone please show me how to work on this problem?

Something wrong here, there would be more possible final scores. Also  probability for score 1 is suspicious $1/2^{15}$ .
